# Do I need to create adapter for every recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am a beginner to android programming. I have created a recycler view which parses data from a JSON. I want to parse another JSON data which has the same data type and same layout everything but it is a different category. do I need to make another adapter for this recycler view?or i can use the same adapter,how i can use? Please help.

My Fragment Code

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements ExampleAdapter.onItemClickListener{
    private RecyclerViewPager mRecyclerView;
    private ExampleAdapter mExampleAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    public static final String EXTRA_URL = "imageUrl";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        // Set the adapter here.
        // Use getActivity() instead of getContext()
        parseJson();
        mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(getContext(), mExampleList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
        mExampleAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(Tab1.this);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void parseJson() {
        String url = "http://maranamassapp.cf/json_getdata.php";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("server_response");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject ser = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String creatorname =  ser.getString("head");
                                String imageUrl = ser.getString("image");
                                String cat = ser.getString("content");
                                String postdate = ser.getString("weburl");
                                String dateall = ser.getString("date");
                                mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(imageUrl,creatorname,cat,postdate,dateall));
                            }

                            // Just call notifyDataSetChanged here
                            mExampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            Intent detailintent = new Intent(getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
            ExampleItem clickeditem = mExampleList.get(position);
            detailintent.putExtra(EXTRA_URL, clickeditem.getmDate());
            startActivity(detailintent);
    }
}
```

My Adapter Code

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>{
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private onItemClickListener mListener;
    public interface onItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }
    public ExampleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExampleItem> examplelist){
        mContext =context;
        mExampleList = examplelist;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.example_item,parent,false);
        return new ExampleViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);
        String imageUrl = currentItem.getmImageUrl();
        String creatorName = currentItem.getmCreator();
        String cat =currentItem.getmCat();
        String postdate = currentItem.getmDate();
        String dateall = currentItem.getmAll();
        holder.mTextViewCreator.setText(creatorName);
        holder.mTextViewCat.setText(cat);
        holder.mDateAll.setText(dateall);
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(holder.mImageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }

    public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextViewCreator;
        public TextView mTextViewCat;
        public TextView mDateAll;
        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            mTextViewCreator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_creator);
            mTextViewCat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_cat);
            mDateAll = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_views);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(mListener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position !=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            mListener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can't help, unless we see the different

Answer (score 1):

Every list needs an adapter, otherwise, it won't display data.

Can more than one list have the same adapter? Absolutely.

If your adapter only can display `ExampleItem` objects that you've stored from somewhere, though, then that's the only type of object you can use in that adapter, and subsequently show in a list. It's not clear what a "category" in your case means.

If you have a different type of object, you need a different adapter class.

If object types share some common values, you might want to brush up on some Java inheritance patterns with abstract classes and Interfaces

Another option is storing more than one ArrayList within an Adapter and using the concept of "item types". For example, all even rows are from one list, and all odd rows from another

---

In this code, if you are using multiple Fragments across multiple tabs, then you will need to use `new ExampleAdapter` and `setAdapter()` individually, many times

Answer (score 1):

if you have two different category and same layout you can you

`getItemViewType(int position)`
method of recyclerview.
below is an example [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView)